Couldn't render images when adding an image to the PDF header via header parameter
I am using https://www.convertapi.com to convert html to pdf but Converter's parameter (https://www.convertapi.com/htm-to-pdf) header and footer accepts a string with the HTML source code. Unfortunately, It couldn't render Images. Tried with base 64 encoding and s3 public object.
enter image description here
Tried this exaample and didn't work
https://help.convertapi.com/en/article/web-to-pdf-header-and-footer-images-and-fonts-patt1g/
